# Rollback to old Nuget package manager in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

Is there any way I can rollback to old Nuget Package Manager (the one which comes with VS2013) for VS 2015, Nuget Package Manager with VS2015 is slow and doesn't even support simple things like update all and if you look at the [reviews provided](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d?SRC=VSIDE) it is just bad :(

I have tried to find the old version thru Tools -> Extensions and Update as shown in the below screen shot.
[image: Install Extensions and Updates]

Just a side note, to update all the current packages that are in project you can go to Package Manager Console <kbd>(Alt + T -> N > O)</kbd> and type "Update-Package" and press enter. This will update all the existing package.

Comment: Try updating. Nuget has released fixes that seem to speed things up a lot.

Comment: I agree, it offers better speed now :)

Comment: For me performance didn't get any better with version 3.2 of Nuget... This is annoying since this is a primary tool when you use Visual Studio.

Comment: The new Nuget is a pile of crap. On slow connections it's impossible to manage multiple packages while waiting 20 seconds for the page to refresh on each change. The lack of multiple select operations are making this impossible to use.

Comment: **Still slow** at the time of writing, now **2016**

Comment: Still slow with 3.4.1 Q2 2016 - the big thing holding back VS2015 as a usable development environment... works perfectly fine in VS2013.

Comment: An update released on March 31st 2106 appears to have resolved the issues for me.  Hopefully for everyone!